# Problem integration new method Plaid ACH with Stripe

Tags: php, laravel, yii, plaid

am trying to integrate Plaid with Stripe but I saw the documentation of Stripe is outdated because now doesn't use PLAID PUBLIC KEY,  use a LINK.

But reviewing the plaid demo https://plaid.com/demo/, I saw a strange behaivor, when I select a bank and I put the credentials, the next step should be show the accounts associate with the bank and I can select the account that I want to use to be associated with stripe and the token for stripe is generated.

But in the demo it does not show the accounts and jumps to the confirmation message that the account was associated.

I have the same behavior in the integration I am doing and cannot pass any account_id to be able to generate the stripe token.

Is that behavior correct?
If so, how can I select an account and obtain the account_id?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you might need to enable Select Account in the developer dashboard.  Select Account should be enabled when using Plaid with an ACH partner integration -- see https://plaid.com/docs-beta/auth/partnerships/stripe/#write-server-side-handler for more info.